# Is it possible to sweep 20 Hz to 20 kHz with one potentiometer?

Tags: audio, analog, filter, potentiometer, active-filter

[image]I'm designing a resonant filter based on a state variable filter topology with sweepable frequency and variable resonance. The filter is designed to sweep from roughly 20 Hz up to 20 kHz (50 kohm linear dual gang potentiometer with 50 ohm limiting resistors and 180 nF capacitors). The prototype works fine and sounds good however, both in the simulation and on the prototype, when turning the potentiometer to sweep the frequency band, 75% of the pot's turn works from 20 Hz to roughly 80 Hz or 100 Hz and the remaining 25% of the pot's turn sweeps up to 20 kHz. Is there a way to sweep the entire audible frequency band using one potentiometer while resolving the pot's sensitivity at high frequency? (cutoff frequency vs pot rotation).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show us the schematics of your filter - simply paste it into your question.

Comment: And check whether you've got a linear pot or a log (audio taper).

Comment: Sorry about that, I've added the schematic to the initial post. And yes, I'm using a linear pot. I've tried different pots both lin and log and still same outcome.

Comment: Ground symbols facing up triggers my PTSD.  Seriously, though, work out the math on those RCs and maybe you will see why this is happening.

Comment: is this why a lot of sweepable audio filters use the rare and mystical anti-log pot?

Answer (score 2):

Frequency  is proportional to 1/(R*C), so it won't be linear with R.

Comment: That's correct, it's inversely proportional. But the math of fc = 1/(2piRC) where R is varied from 50 ohm to 50 kohm plots differently from what the simulation and prototype are showing.

Comment: Hi, Ryan: The usual schematic for this kind of filter does not have grounded pots connected as you have drawn.  Usually, the pots are just variable resistors, acting as the input resistors of the integrators. Did you make a mistake here?  Try fixing that. Also, depending on your op amp, At high frequencies loop gain is low and the simple equations won’t be quite right. Is it at high frequencies that you see the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've removed the grounding off the pots in the simulation software and the prototype that I've built has the third terminal of the pots left unconnected. Yes, the issue is at high frequencies. The pot sweeps from 1 kHz up to 20 kHz on the last 25% of the pots turn whereas the first 75% of the pot's turn sweeps 20 Hz up to 100 Hz (roughly).

Comment: Hi, Ryan. Doesn’t that make sense if f=1/(2*pi*R*C)? Seems to be working as it should.....

Comment: I'm with you 100%. Totally makes sense. Do you think it's possible to sweep the entire audible frequency band with one potentiometer while evening out the cutoff frequency vs pot rotation so it won't sweep so fast at high frequencies?

Comment: If it were me, I would make the filter electrically tunable. Then I would use a microcontroller to read the pot and set the frequency of the filter, based on the pot value. Find an electronically variable filter using multiplying a/d converters, for example. The microcontroller can do any calculations necessary to make the control linear with its setting.

Comment: Thank you. I'm wondering if it can be done purely in the analog domain.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the output impedance of U2 is 0 ohms across the frequency band of interest.  If so, then the impedance seen by the U3 circuit is 50 ohms at one end of the FREQ1 pot rotation, 0 ohms at the other end, and approx. 12.5K ohms in the center.  Same for the U3 circuit.  This introduces a non-linearity into the circuit's response to pot rotation.

Both pots should be connected as variable series resistances rather than voltage dividers.  This eliminates the other problem, where 100% of the signal goes away at one end of the pot rotation.

Comment: Thank you! I believe this is the issue. Do you have any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Wouldn't leaving the third terminal of the pots unconnected make it a variable resistor rather than a voltage divider? disregard the fact that the pots are grounded in this schematic. In my prototype, the unused terminals are left unconnected. I'm sorry if what i'm saying doesn't make sense haha.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you made mistake in your potentiometers characteristics.
Take in mind that in USA key `A` means `log` potentiometer, and key `B` means `linear`.
In Europe this is in opposition: key `A` means `linear` potentiometer, and key `B` means `log`.

Comment: I've taken that into consideration and double-checked the datasheets and everything tracks. I think the circuit is affecting the pots since the simulation also shows the same discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

You designed a 1/R controlled value to alter hi/lo freq. BW in a k1/R= ***f1*** for centre frequency in an RC active BPF.

Instead you should have inverted R value in software then sent to Pot and calibrate for those values.

division= use 2's compliment and add with carry removed.

Also you have the Pot's shown as attenuators so you lose the signal at the same time.

**Do not ground signal on Pots!**

Comment: I've added a schematic to my original post to clear things up. I believe you're referring to digital audio? Whereas my design is purely analogue.

Comment: correct answer above now

Comment: Thank you! I think I understand what you're saying but could you elaborate more with reference to the schematic to better understand? That would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Use only 2 pins on the Pots

Comment: Unlike the schematic above, I am only using 2 pins on the potentiometers. The unused terminals are left unconnected and still, there are non-linearities.

Comment: @Ryan The logical test  is verify your assumptions using an Ohm Meter and scope. NO excuse for not including assumptions , datasheet and verifications in question.